# Iternate through Json file with missing indexes

Tags: php, json, indexing

I have a Json file `$championsList` that skips a bunch numbers in its indexes. For example, `$championsList["data"][46]` doesn't exist and towards the bottom it skips from 268 to 412. There's a bunch more scattered throughout.

I tried writing a for loop to iterate through the  `["data"]` index as a test.

```
for($i=1; $i <= sizeof($championsList["data"]; $i++) {
    echo $championsList["data"][$i]["key"];
    }
```

The problem with this is, the size of the `["data"]` index is 136, so when it gets to the end of the loop it does `echo $championsList["data"][136]["key"];` and stops, skipping everything with a number higher than 136 because it also iterates through indexes that don't exist  like`echo $championsList["data"][$46]["key"];`

I know I can just do

```
for($i=1; $i <= 498; $i++) {
    echo ...
}
```

but that seems pretty inefficient and I'd have to keep adjusting it when new characters are added to the game

How can I make it so that it iterates and skips all of the missing numbers?

The Json file:

```
{
  "type": "champion",
  "version": "7.10.1",
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "key": "Annie",
      "name": "Annie",
      "title": "the Dark Child"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "key": "Olaf",
      "name": "Olaf",
      "title": "the Berserker"
    },
    "3": {
      "id": 3,
      "key": "Galio",
      "name": "Galio",
      "title": "the Colossus"
    },
    "4": {
      "id": 4,
      "key": "TwistedFate",
      "name": "Twisted Fate",
      "title": "the Card Master"
    },
    "5": {
      "id": 5,
      "key": "XinZhao",
      "name": "Xin Zhao",
      "title": "the Seneschal of Demacia"
    },
    "6": {
      "id": 6,
      "key": "Urgot",
      "name": "Urgot",
      "title": "the Headsman's Pride"
    },
    "7": {
      "id": 7,
      "key": "Leblanc",
      "name": "LeBlanc",
      "title": "the Deceiver"
    },
    "8": {
      "id": 8,
      "key": "Vladimir",
      "name": "Vladimir",
      "title": "the Crimson Reaper"
    },
    "9": {
      "id": 9,
      "key": "Fiddlesticks",
      "name": "Fiddlesticks",
      "title": "the Harbinger of Doom"
    },
    "10": {
      "id": 10,
      "key": "Kayle",
      "name": "Kayle",
      "title": "The Judicator"
    },
    "11": {
      "id": 11,
      "key": "MasterYi",
      "name": "Master Yi",
      "title": "the Wuju Bladesman"
    },
    "12": {
      "id": 12,
      "key": "Alistar",
      "name": "Alistar",
      "title": "the Minotaur"
    },
    "13": {
      "id": 13,
      "key": "Ryze",
      "name": "Ryze",
      "title": "the Rune Mage"
    },
    "14": {
      "id": 14,
      "key": "Sion",
      "name": "Sion",
      "title": "The Undead Juggernaut"
    },
    "15": {
      "id": 15,
      "key": "Sivir",
      "name": "Sivir",
      "title": "the Battle Mistress"
    },
    "16": {
      "id": 16,
      "key": "Soraka",
      "name": "Soraka",
      "title": "the Starchild"
    },
    "17": {
      "id": 17,
      "key": "Teemo",
      "name": "Teemo",
      "title": "the Swift Scout"
    },
    "18": {
      "id": 18,
      "key": "Tristana",
      "name": "Tristana",
      "title": "the Yordle Gunner"
    },
    "19": {
      "id": 19,
      "key": "Warwick",
      "name": "Warwick",
      "title": "the Uncaged Wrath of Zaun"
    },
    "20": {
      "id": 20,
      "key": "Nunu",
      "name": "Nunu",
      "title": "the Yeti Rider"
    },
    "21": {
      "id": 21,
      "key": "MissFortune",
      "name": "Miss Fortune",
      "title": "the Bounty Hunter"
    },
    "22": {
      "id": 22,
      "key": "Ashe",
      "name": "Ashe",
      "title": "the Frost Archer"
    },
    "23": {
      "id": 23,
      "key": "Tryndamere",
      "name": "Tryndamere",
      "title": "the Barbarian King"
    },
    "24": {
      "id": 24,
      "key": "Jax",
      "name": "Jax",
      "title": "Grandmaster at Arms"
    },
    "25": {
      "id": 25,
      "key": "Morgana",
      "name": "Morgana",
      "title": "Fallen Angel"
    },
    "26": {
      "id": 26,
      "key": "Zilean",
      "name": "Zilean",
      "title": "the Chronokeeper"
    },
    "27": {
      "id": 27,
      "key": "Singed",
      "name": "Singed",
      "title": "the Mad Chemist"
    },
    "28": {
      "id": 28,
      "key": "Evelynn",
      "name": "Evelynn",
      "title": "the Widowmaker"
    },
    "29": {
      "id": 29,
      "key": "Twitch",
      "name": "Twitch",
      "title": "the Plague Rat"
    },
    "30": {
      "id": 30,
      "key": "Karthus",
      "name": "Karthus",
      "title": "the Deathsinger"
    },
    "31": {
      "id": 31,
      "key": "Chogath",
      "name": "Cho'Gath",
      "title": "the Terror of the Void"
    },
    "32": {
      "id": 32,
      "key": "Amumu",
      "name": "Amumu",
      "title": "the Sad Mummy"
    },
    "33": {
      "id": 33,
      "key": "Rammus",
      "name": "Rammus",
      "title": "the Armordillo"
    },
    "34": {
      "id": 34,
      "key": "Anivia",
      "name": "Anivia",
      "title": "the Cryophoenix"
    },
    "35": {
      "id": 35,
      "key": "Shaco",
      "name": "Shaco",
      "title": "the Demon Jester"
    },
    "36": {
      "id": 36,
      "key": "DrMundo",
      "name": "Dr. Mundo",
      "title": "the Madman of Zaun"
    },
    "37": {
      "id": 37,
      "key": "Sona",
      "name": "Sona",
      "title": "Maven of the Strings"
    },
    "38": {
      "id": 38,
      "key": "Kassadin",
      "name": "Kassadin",
      "title": "the Void Walker"
    },
    "39": {
      "id": 39,
      "key": "Irelia",
      "name": "Irelia",
      "title": "the Will of the Blades"
    },
    "40": {
      "id": 40,
      "key": "Janna",
      "name": "Janna",
      "title": "the Storm's Fury"
    },
    "41": {
      "id": 41,
      "key": "Gangplank",
      "name": "Gangplank",
      "title": "the Saltwater Scourge"
    },
    "42": {
      "id": 42,
      "key": "Corki",
      "name": "Corki",
      "title": "the Daring Bombardier"
    },
    "43": {
      "id": 43,
      "key": "Karma",
      "name": "Karma",
      "title": "the Enlightened One"
    },
    "44": {
      "id": 44,
      "key": "Taric",
      "name": "Taric",
      "title": "the Shield of Valoran"
    },
    "45": {
      "id": 45,
      "key": "Veigar",
      "name": "Veigar",
      "title": "the Tiny Master of Evil"
    },
    "48": {
      "id": 48,
      "key": "Trundle",
      "name": "Trundle",
      "title": "the Troll King"
    },
    "50": {
      "id": 50,
      "key": "Swain",
      "name": "Swain",
      "title": "the Master Tactician"
    },
    "51": {
      "id": 51,
      "key": "Caitlyn",
      "name": "Caitlyn",
      "title": "the Sheriff of Piltover"
    },
    "53": {
      "id": 53,
      "key": "Blitzcrank",
      "name": "Blitzcrank",
      "title": "the Great Steam Golem"
    },
    "54": {
      "id": 54,
      "key": "Malphite",
      "name": "Malphite",
      "title": "Shard of the Monolith"
    },
    "55": {
      "id": 55,
      "key": "Katarina",
      "name": "Katarina",
      "title": "the Sinister Blade"
    },
    "56": {
      "id": 56,
      "key": "Nocturne",
      "name": "Nocturne",
      "title": "the Eternal Nightmare"
    },
    "57": {
      "id": 57,
      "key": "Maokai",
      "name": "Maokai",
      "title": "the Twisted Treant"
    },
    "58": {
      "id": 58,
      "key": "Renekton",
      "name": "Renekton",
      "title": "the Butcher of the Sands"
    },
    "59": {
      "id": 59,
      "key": "JarvanIV",
      "name": "Jarvan IV",
      "title": "the Exemplar of Demacia"
    },
    "60": {
      "id": 60,
      "key": "Elise",
      "name": "Elise",
      "title": "the Spider Queen"
    },
    "61": {
      "id": 61,
      "key": "Orianna",
      "name": "Orianna",
      "title": "the Lady of Clockwork"
    },
    "62": {
      "id": 62,
      "key": "MonkeyKing",
      "name": "Wukong",
      "title": "the Monkey King"
    },
    "63": {
      "id": 63,
      "key": "Brand",
      "name": "Brand",
      "title": "the Burning Vengeance"
    },
    "64": {
      "id": 64,
      "key": "LeeSin",
      "name": "Lee Sin",
      "title": "the Blind Monk"
    },
    "67": {
      "id": 67,
      "key": "Vayne",
      "name": "Vayne",
      "title": "the Night Hunter"
    },
    "68": {
      "id": 68,
      "key": "Rumble",
      "name": "Rumble",
      "title": "the Mechanized Menace"
    },
    "69": {
      "id": 69,
      "key": "Cassiopeia",
      "name": "Cassiopeia",
      "title": "the Serpent's Embrace"
    },
    "72": {
      "id": 72,
      "key": "Skarner",
      "name": "Skarner",
      "title": "the Crystal Vanguard"
    },
    "74": {
      "id": 74,
      "key": "Heimerdinger",
      "name": "Heimerdinger",
      "title": "the Revered Inventor"
    },
    "75": {
      "id": 75,
      "key": "Nasus",
      "name": "Nasus",
      "title": "the Curator of the Sands"
    },
    "76": {
      "id": 76,
      "key": "Nidalee",
      "name": "Nidalee",
      "title": "the Bestial Huntress"
    },
    "77": {
      "id": 77,
      "key": "Udyr",
      "name": "Udyr",
      "title": "the Spirit Walker"
    },
    "78": {
      "id": 78,
      "key": "Poppy",
      "name": "Poppy",
      "title": "Keeper of the Hammer"
    },
    "79": {
      "id": 79,
      "key": "Gragas",
      "name": "Gragas",
      "title": "the Rabble Rouser"
    },
    "80": {
      "id": 80,
      "key": "Pantheon",
      "name": "Pantheon",
      "title": "the Artisan of War"
    },
    "81": {
      "id": 81,
      "key": "Ezreal",
      "name": "Ezreal",
      "title": "the Prodigal Explorer"
    },
    "82": {
      "id": 82,
      "key": "Mordekaiser",
      "name": "Mordekaiser",
      "title": "the Iron Revenant"
    },
    "83": {
      "id": 83,
      "key": "Yorick",
      "name": "Yorick",
      "title": "Shepherd of Souls"
    },
    "84": {
      "id": 84,
      "key": "Akali",
      "name": "Akali",
      "title": "the Fist of Shadow"
    },
    "85": {
      "id": 85,
      "key": "Kennen",
      "name": "Kennen",
      "title": "the Heart of the Tempest"
    },
    "86": {
      "id": 86,
      "key": "Garen",
      "name": "Garen",
      "title": "The Might of Demacia"
    },
    "89": {
      "id": 89,
      "key": "Leona",
      "name": "Leona",
      "title": "the Radiant Dawn"
    },
    "90": {
      "id": 90,
      "key": "Malzahar",
      "name": "Malzahar",
      "title": "the Prophet of the Void"
    },
    "91": {
      "id": 91,
      "key": "Talon",
      "name": "Talon",
      "title": "the Blade's Shadow"
    },
    "92": {
      "id": 92,
      "key": "Riven",
      "name": "Riven",
      "title": "the Exile"
    },
    "96": {
      "id": 96,
      "key": "KogMaw",
      "name": "Kog'Maw",
      "title": "the Mouth of the Abyss"
    },
    "98": {
      "id": 98,
      "key": "Shen",
      "name": "Shen",
      "title": "the Eye of Twilight"
    },
    "99": {
      "id": 99,
      "key": "Lux",
      "name": "Lux",
      "title": "the Lady of Luminosity"
    },
    "101": {
      "id": 101,
      "key": "Xerath",
      "name": "Xerath",
      "title": "the Magus Ascendant"
    },
    "102": {
      "id": 102,
      "key": "Shyvana",
      "name": "Shyvana",
      "title": "the Half-Dragon"
    },
    "103": {
      "id": 103,
      "key": "Ahri",
      "name": "Ahri",
      "title": "the Nine-Tailed Fox"
    },
    "104": {
      "id": 104,
      "key": "Graves",
      "name": "Graves",
      "title": "the Outlaw"
    },
    "105": {
      "id": 105,
      "key": "Fizz",
      "name": "Fizz",
      "title": "the Tidal Trickster"
    },
    "106": {
      "id": 106,
      "key": "Volibear",
      "name": "Volibear",
      "title": "the Thunder's Roar"
    },
    "107": {
      "id": 107,
      "key": "Rengar",
      "name": "Rengar",
      "title": "the Pridestalker"
    },
    "110": {
      "id": 110,
      "key": "Varus",
      "name": "Varus",
      "title": "the Arrow of Retribution"
    },
    "111": {
      "id": 111,
      "key": "Nautilus",
      "name": "Nautilus",
      "title": "the Titan of the Depths"
    },
    "112": {
      "id": 112,
      "key": "Viktor",
      "name": "Viktor",
      "title": "the Machine Herald"
    },
    "113": {
      "id": 113,
      "key": "Sejuani",
      "name": "Sejuani",
      "title": "Fury of the North"
    },
    "114": {
      "id": 114,
      "key": "Fiora",
      "name": "Fiora",
      "title": "the Grand Duelist"
    },
    "115": {
      "id": 115,
      "key": "Ziggs",
      "name": "Ziggs",
      "title": "the Hexplosives Expert"
    },
    "117": {
      "id": 117,
      "key": "Lulu",
      "name": "Lulu",
      "title": "the Fae Sorceress"
    },
    "119": {
      "id": 119,
      "key": "Draven",
      "name": "Draven",
      "title": "the Glorious Executioner"
    },
    "120": {
      "id": 120,
      "key": "Hecarim",
      "name": "Hecarim",
      "title": "the Shadow of War"
    },
    "121": {
      "id": 121,
      "key": "Khazix",
      "name": "Kha'Zix",
      "title": "the Voidreaver"
    },
    "122": {
      "id": 122,
      "key": "Darius",
      "name": "Darius",
      "title": "the Hand of Noxus"
    },
    "126": {
      "id": 126,
      "key": "Jayce",
      "name": "Jayce",
      "title": "the Defender of Tomorrow"
    },
    "127": {
      "id": 127,
      "key": "Lissandra",
      "name": "Lissandra",
      "title": "the Ice Witch"
    },
    "131": {
      "id": 131,
      "key": "Diana",
      "name": "Diana",
      "title": "Scorn of the Moon"
    },
    "133": {
      "id": 133,
      "key": "Quinn",
      "name": "Quinn",
      "title": "Demacia's Wings"
    },
    "134": {
      "id": 134,
      "key": "Syndra",
      "name": "Syndra",
      "title": "the Dark Sovereign"
    },
    "136": {
      "id": 136,
      "key": "AurelionSol",
      "name": "Aurelion Sol",
      "title": "The Star Forger"
    },
    "143": {
      "id": 143,
      "key": "Zyra",
      "name": "Zyra",
      "title": "Rise of the Thorns"
    },
    "150": {
      "id": 150,
      "key": "Gnar",
      "name": "Gnar",
      "title": "the Missing Link"
    },
    "154": {
      "id": 154,
      "key": "Zac",
      "name": "Zac",
      "title": "the Secret Weapon"
    },
    "157": {
      "id": 157,
      "key": "Yasuo",
      "name": "Yasuo",
      "title": "the Unforgiven"
    },
    "161": {
      "id": 161,
      "key": "Velkoz",
      "name": "Vel'Koz",
      "title": "the Eye of the Void"
    },
    "163": {
      "id": 163,
      "key": "Taliyah",
      "name": "Taliyah",
      "title": "the Stoneweaver"
    },
    "164": {
      "id": 164,
      "key": "Camille",
      "name": "Camille",
      "title": "the Steel Shadow"
    },
    "201": {
      "id": 201,
      "key": "Braum",
      "name": "Braum",
      "title": "the Heart of the Freljord"
    },
    "202": {
      "id": 202,
      "key": "Jhin",
      "name": "Jhin",
      "title": "the Virtuoso"
    },
    "203": {
      "id": 203,
      "key": "Kindred",
      "name": "Kindred",
      "title": "The Eternal Hunters"
    },
    "222": {
      "id": 222,
      "key": "Jinx",
      "name": "Jinx",
      "title": "the Loose Cannon"
    },
    "223": {
      "id": 223,
      "key": "TahmKench",
      "name": "Tahm Kench",
      "title": "the River King"
    },
    "236": {
      "id": 236,
      "key": "Lucian",
      "name": "Lucian",
      "title": "the Purifier"
    },
    "238": {
      "id": 238,
      "key": "Zed",
      "name": "Zed",
      "title": "the Master of Shadows"
    },
    "240": {
      "id": 240,
      "key": "Kled",
      "name": "Kled",
      "title": "the Cantankerous Cavalier"
    },
    "245": {
      "id": 245,
      "key": "Ekko",
      "name": "Ekko",
      "title": "the Boy Who Shattered Time"
    },
    "254": {
      "id": 254,
      "key": "Vi",
      "name": "Vi",
      "title": "the Piltover Enforcer"
    },
    "266": {
      "id": 266,
      "key": "Aatrox",
      "name": "Aatrox",
      "title": "the Darkin Blade"
    },
    "267": {
      "id": 267,
      "key": "Nami",
      "name": "Nami",
      "title": "the Tidecaller"
    },
    "268": {
      "id": 268,
      "key": "Azir",
      "name": "Azir",
      "title": "the Emperor of the Sands"
    },
    "412": {
      "id": 412,
      "key": "Thresh",
      "name": "Thresh",
      "title": "the Chain Warden"
    },
    "420": {
      "id": 420,
      "key": "Illaoi",
      "name": "Illaoi",
      "title": "the Kraken Priestess"
    },
    "421": {
      "id": 421,
      "key": "RekSai",
      "name": "Rek'Sai",
      "title": "the Void Burrower"
    },
    "427": {
      "id": 427,
      "key": "Ivern",
      "name": "Ivern",
      "title": "the Green Father"
    },
    "429": {
      "id": 429,
      "key": "Kalista",
      "name": "Kalista",
      "title": "the Spear of Vengeance"
    },
    "432": {
      "id": 432,
      "key": "Bard",
      "name": "Bard",
      "title": "the Wandering Caretaker"
    },
    "497": {
      "id": 497,
      "key": "Rakan",
      "name": "Rakan",
      "title": "The Charmer"
    },
    "498": {
      "id": 498,
      "key": "Xayah",
      "name": "Xayah",
      "title": "the Rebel"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: foreach ($championsList["data"] as $item) { echo $item['key']; ...

Comment: Why is posting the ENTIRE json file necessary in this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want foreach, which will consider each element regardless of its index:  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
foreach($championsList["data"] as $champion) {
    echo $champion["key"];
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks man. I also noticed that the list is now in a random order, which is fine. I just found it interesting. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

another way is to use foreach loop ..

```
foreach($championsList["data"] as $key => $val) {
    echo $key;
    var_dump($val);
}
```